# What is a signal distributing device called?

Tags: voltage

I have a DC power source of 5v which I want to distribute to a few circuits (amplifier, motor driver etc.). But I couldn't figure out a component that we can use for splitting the power to a line on which you can connect jumper wires to (Please see the image.).

[image]

Comment: It soundls like you are looking for a busbar?

Comment: The title says "signal" but the question says "power". It may worth clarifying which because the answers may differ.

Comment: It reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard

Comment: Connect jumper wires, use a pin header, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_header Some soldering might be required to connect the pins together though. This can be done quite easily on some prototype board, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard

Comment: Depending whether your squares are holes or pins, Zola or FakeMoustache are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes in various names and shapes, but you are looking for a **Busbar**, **Terminal Strip**, **Terminal Block**, or **Distribution Block**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you are looking to distribute lower amperage signals, then something like a breadboard, or a telephone punchdown block would work.

[image] [image]

Comment: That was the most helpful answer!